# Extract values from factoextra package

Tags: r, statistics, analysis

I am using this code for Multiple Correspondence Analysis (MCA):

```
fviz_cos2(res.mca, choice= 'var', axes= 1:2)
```

Where I get a barr plot for dimensions 1-2, but I would like to know how I could get values for each barr.
[image]

I've tried with different aproaches, but I do not get the values of the barr plot:

```
# Get the individual coordinates of the MCA
ind<- get_mca_ind(res.mca)
# Select the first two dimensions of coordinates of variables
scores<-ind$coord[,1:2]
head(ind$cos2[,1:2])
```

I would like to share some of the data, but due to its complexity, I am able to share this.
So how can I get a table with the values or calculate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems that you are extracting cos2 for the individuals whereas you need cos2 for the categories : `var<- get_mca_var(res.mca);head(var$cos2[,1:2])`

Comment: Thanks! I've just found the solution, was as simple as: ```res.mca$var$cos2``` and I get the values for each dimension

Answer (score 0):

To find the values for cos2 of 'factorextra package', just use to see the values of each dimension

```
res.mca$var$cos2
```